# how to explain this code : if (strstr(line, *argv) != EOF) != except

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, argv

Its in K&R.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char *line, int max);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

     char line[MAXLINE];
     long lineno = 0;
     int c, except = 0, number = 0, found = 0;

     while(--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-') 
        while(c = *++argv[0])                 
          switch(c) {
             case 'x':
                  except = 1;
                  break;
             case 'n':
                  number = 1;
                  break;
             default:
                  printf("find: illegal option %c\n", c);
                  argc = 0;
                  found = -1;
                  break;
          }
    if (argc != 1)
        printf("Usage : find -x, -n, pattern\n");
     else 
    while(getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0) {
       lineno++;
        if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except) {
           if (number)
              printf("%ld", lineno);
           printf("%s", line);
              found++;     
      }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what this statement means: `if (strstr(line, *argv) != EOF) != expect)` there was some mistakes before and i correctd it.

However, when i try to understand it ,i have some troubles.

Here is what i think: `find -x -n`. So, the `argc = 3`. `argv[0] = find`. `argv[1] = -x`. `argv[2] = -n`. `argv[3] = NULL`. After the first while loop, shouldn't the `argc = 0`. so i am confused.

Comment: when I try to compile it, I get a series of errors: http://hastebin.com/evatomigad.js I'm tempted to say that that line as written doesn't really mean anything. there's some obviously imbalanced parentheses, and "expect" doesn't appear elsewhere in the code

Comment: if you change expect to "except", and add parentheses, and if you add a definition for getline then I think it would compile. EOF is a macro in C that stands for "end of file reached" signal. So the inner "!=" is checking "end of file reached", and the second "!= except" is checking whether the first check was what we expected

Comment: sorry , i've written something wrong, the right statement is : if (strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != expcet). i checked again, expcet this, there is nothing wrong, i totally copied from the book.

Comment: if it doesn't compile then the book is wrong, or you overlooked something. the compiler is more authoritative than the book (from a practical point of view)

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong in many ways. But specially because it is comparing a pointer to an integer. The `strstr()` function returns a pointer, and `EOF` is an integer. The parameters are fine, if the comparison was made with `NULL` instead it would be testing if the first value `argv` points to, contains the text in `line`. Remember that the `argv` can be incremented to point to the next element in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The example is from K&R 2nd Edition, section 5.10 "Command-line Arguments".

The example is given to illustrate `strstr()`, pointer handling, and adding some options to a command line program:

> The standard library function `strstr(s,t)` returns a pointer to the
>   first occurrence of the string `t` in the string `s`, or `NULL` if
>   there is none. It is declared in `<string.h>`.
>
> The model can now be elaborated to illustrate further pointer
>   constructions. Suppose we want to allow two optional arguments. One
>   says "print all the lines except those that match the pattern;" the
>   second says "precede each printed line by its line number."

To answer your specific question about the meaning of:

```
if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except)  // note: NULL, not EOF
```

The answer is that the `strstr()` call will return a non-NULL pointer if the string passed as a command line argument is found in the line and NULL otherwise. So the sub-expression

```
(strstr(line, *argv) != NULL)
```

evaluates to:

```
true    - argument is found (a 'match')
false   - argument is not found (a 'non-match')
```

The variable `except` is set via an option with the following meaning:

```
true    - print non-matching lines
false   - print matching lines (the default)
```

So, the full expression determines if the line should be printed or not according to whether it contains the argument and whether the option to print matching or non-matching lines is given.

Comment: thank you so much ,i get it. however i have another question and i hope you can help me.  i think the first while loop that makes argc = 0, i knew it's wrong but why

Comment: @Micheal: I'm not sure what you're asking about `argc`.  With a good command line, `argc` will end up as 1 - otherwise the program will print out an error message and not process the standard input. Remember you have to give a 'pattern' argument for the program to have anything.to do.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong. Though I don't have K&R, I rewrite it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

// Dummy Array
static char fooString[2][MAXLINE] = {
   "abcdefg\n",
   "hijklm\n" 
};

// dummy function
int myGetline(char **line, int maxline) {
    static int i = 0;
    char *tmp = fooString[i++];
    if (strlen(tmp) > maxline) {
        *line = '\0';
        return 0;
    }
    *line = tmp;
    return strlen(tmp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Mod Start ---
    //char line[MAXLINE];
    char *line = NULL;
    // Mod End   ---
    long lineno = 0;
    size_t length = 0;
    int c, except = 0, number = 0, found = 0;
    // Mod start ---
    //while (--argc > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-') {
    // equals ...
    int idx_i = 0;
    int idx_j = 0;
    while (--argc > 0 && argv[++idx_i][0] == '-') {
    // Mod End   ---
        // Mod start ---
        //while (c = *++(argv[0])) {
        // equals ...
        idx_j = 0;
        while (c = argv[idx_i][++idx_j]) {
        // Mod End   ---
            switch (c) {
            case 'x':
                except = 1;
                break;
            case 'n':
                number = 1;
                break;
            default:
                printf("find : illigal option %c\n", c);
                found = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (argc != 1) {
        printf("Usage: find -x -n pattern\n");
    }
    else {
        while (myGetline(&line, MAXLINE) > 0) {
            // Mod start ---
            //if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except) {
            // equals ...
            if ((strstr(line, argv[idx_i]) != NULL) != except) {
            // Mod End ---
                if (number) {
                    printf("%ld:", lineno);
                }
                printf("%s", line);
                found++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (found ? 0 : -1); 
}
```

Complie:

```
$ gcc -o find.exe find.c
```

Result:

```
$ ./find.exe -n -x abc
0:hijklm
```

X means EXCEPT, not expect...

`if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != except)` equals the code below.

```
if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) {
    if (except) {
```

Comment: thank you . i have trouble understanding the first while loop. after the loop, shouldn't the argc = 0?

Comment: Yes. argc = 0 at the end of first while loop.  In the first loop, argv is increaed. And End of the first loop, argv points &argv[3][0] in this example. Sorry, I am not good at English...

Comment: however, if argc = 0 at the end of the loop, the if sentence will not work

Comment: argc = 1 at the end of first while loop, not argc = 0. I mistaken. No, Im Japanese.

Comment: sorry i can't get it, would you mind writing more specific? why the argc = 1 at the end?

Comment: You shoud insert the code printf("%d\n", argc"); above. It might help you understand. The reason is that at the part of while (--argc > 0 ...,  when argc equals 1, then break the loop.

Comment: (*++argv)[0] != '-', then break the loop. only one argument with no '-' allow to pass the program.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **pattern** in the end of ‘find -x -n’. if missed, then argc=0, it will print the sentence: Usage: find -x -n pattern.